# Time complexity for FPT algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, colorings, parameterized-complexity

I'm studying the issue of FPT algorithms and came to the k-disjoint triangles problem as can be seen
[here](https://www-sop.inria.fr/mascotte/seminaires/AGAPE/lecture_notes/Agape%2009%20-%20Daniel%20Marx%20-%20FPT%20algorithmic%20techniques%20-%20Printable.pdf) on slide 60.

The problem summary is given a graph G and variable k, are there k disjoint triangles in the graph.
There are two methods, I want to focus on one of them. (Method 1)

First I randomly color the graph in 3k colors and then go over each permutation of colors and check whether there are k triangles with distinct colors.

What I fail to understand is what the time complexity of such examination (going over all the possible permutations) and how exactly can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have a graph and each vertex is colored with one of three colors, and let the set of different-colored vertices be $A, B, C$.

Now, try to find a triangle with one vertex from each partition.  For each vertex $a \in A$, try let $B_a$ and $C_a$ be $a$'s neighborhood in $B$ and $C$, respectively.  Now you only need to check if there is an edge from $B_a$ to $C_a$.  If there is one, you have your triangle, otherwise, you try another vertex from $A$.

Let us call this subroutine `colorful_triangle(G, A, B, C)`.  Observe that it is not necessary that $A \cup B \cup C = V(G)$.

---

Let $G$ be the graph, $\chi$ the coloring and  $\pi$ a permutation of colors.

Let $\chi(i)$ be the set of vertices that received color $i$.

Now let $A = \chi(\pi(1))$, $B = \chi(\pi(2))$, $C = \chi(\pi(3))$.  Run the subrouting `colorful_triangle(G, A, B, C)`.  If successful, continue with
$A = \chi(\pi(4))$, $B = \chi(\pi(5))$, $C = \chi(\pi(6))$, and so on.

If you at some point are unsuccessful, move on to the next permutation.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I need to check for each three colors, whether I have a triangle with those colors, if I find one, I can move on to the next three colors. Otherwise, I should try a different permutation. What could be the worst case in timewise regards?

Comment: Correct. And since you try all permutations of colours, then you'll find $k$ triangles if it is a yes instance.