# Color coding to get an FPT algoirthm for k disjoint triangles

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, np, colorings, parameterized-complexity

The k-disjoint triangles problem is as follows:

> Input: A graph $G=(V,E)$ and an integer $k\in \mathbb{N}$
>
> Output: Are there $k$ vertex-disjoint triangles in $G$?

An FPT algorithm is presented [here](https://www-sop.inria.fr/mascotte/seminaires/AGAPE/lecture_notes/Agape%2009%20-%20Daniel%20Marx%20-%20FPT%20algorithmic%20techniques%20-%20Printable.pdf)
(starting from slide 60). The algorithm uses color-coding and relies on dynamic programming to determine if a solution is highlighted (each vertex in the solution group is colored with a distinct color). The running time of the algorithm is $O^∗((2e)^{3k})$.

I`m trying to understand the running time of this algorithm using dynamic programming (method 2). why is it   $O^∗((2e)^{3k})$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time complexity for FPT algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/139511/time-complexity-for-fpt-algorithm)

Comment: no, the answer is for the first method while I asked about the second method. and still i don`t understand why is it O∗((2e)3k)?

Comment: This came up recently, and IIRC the $(2e)^{3k}$ comes from $e^{3k}2^{3k}$, where the first factor is the number of random colourings you need to try to get a constant probability of success (in the case of a YES instance), and the second factor is the time needed to solve the DP for each colouring.

Comment: As @j_random_hacker says, it comes from random colorings.  An easier example is the example for $k$-PATH on page 54 in the same deck.  Now, instead of a $k$-PATH you are looking for $k$ triangles.

Comment: I guess I didn`t make myself clear enough. but my main problem is that I`m not able to see why the DP can be done in 2^3k. how is it possible? as I see it everytime I check a new cell value, I need to check many of his subgroups and I can`t see  how it gets done in O(2^3k)

Comment: You go over all subsets of $[3k]$ whose size is a multiple of 3, in order. For each one, you need to try $O(n^3)$ possibilities. Trying out each possibilities requires a single table look-up, though preparing the index could perhaps take some time (the exact time depends on the model of computation).

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic programming algorithm goes over all subsets of $[3k]$ whose size is a multiple of 3, in nondecreasing order of size. For each such non-empty subset, it goes over all $O(n^3)$ triplets of vertices, and for each one, it performs a single table look-up. Therefore the running time is $O^*(2^{3k} n^3)$, where $O^*$ hides $\operatorname{poly}(k)$ factors which are needed to manipulate indices.